# logstash settings are invalid

Tags: configuration, logstash, elk

I'am trying to start logstash on windows with a custom conf file but I get always the same error :
Your settings are invalid. Reason: Setting "" doesn't exist. Please check if you haven't made a typo.

this is my conf:

```
input {
   file {   
      type => "syslog"
      path => "C:/log/log.log"
   }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
    index =>"myindex"
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not look like an error with the conf file but something with the settings file. Could you verify your logstash.yml file has correct settings

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using windows. Hence , in the configuration replace the slash mentioned below

```
path => "C:\log\log.log"
```

then execute the below command to verify you configuration is syntactically correct

```
logstash --config.test_and_exit -f "<YOUR-FILENAME-ALONG-WITH-FILEPATH"
```

This would give us conclusion whether it is wrong with logstash configuration or with your setup.

Keep posted with updates!!! Thanks